# Videojs player html5 and remote video

Tags: html5-video, video.js

Hello I have a problem with videojs player,

I have mp4 videos on one file server and mp4 video on my main server.

When I start some video and video is on my main server the loading is ok, but if I try to start a video that is on file server, video doesn't start.

The patch is correct.

with flowplayer works fine, have you some ideas to fix this problem?

Comment: what does your current code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my ffmpeg patch was wrong, I usend ffmpeg installed with: yum install ffmpeg instead of /bin/ffmpeg installed manually

I change ffmpeg's url in my script and now works fine!